# Displaying a button on each post

Tags: php, posts, buttons

I'm trying to add a button for each post.

```
add_action( 'the_post', [ $this, 'myButton' ] );
public function myButton( $post ) {

      $this->ID = $post->ID;
      $myId=$post->ID;
      echo "<button onclick=\"buttonAction()\" p style=\"font-size:10px\" id=\"ActionButton\">ACTION</button>";
}
```

This works well, but there is a problem, it not only appears in post, but also on homepage above each post and at all pages that contains a link to post. Additionally I can't style for displaying it at the proper place, it is on the top of post. How can i style it, and make it only appear on post's webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `the_content` hook and hook only when you are on a single page:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_button_function' );

function my_button_function( $content ) {

    // See if it's a single post or a loop
    if ( is_single() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) {
        return $content . "<button onclick=\"buttonAction()\" p style=\"font-size:10px\" id=\"ActionButton\">ACTION</button>";
    }

    return $content;
}
```

This will only add the button if you are on a single post, and will add the button at the end of your content.

Further reading at : [WordPress Developer's website](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/).